# Microsoft Graph API for SharePoint in Python: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError

Tags: excel, rest, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

We are sending out the following query:

```
{u'parentReference': {u'path': u'/drive/root:/Main'}, u'name': u'BusinessDailyTemplate.xlsb'}
```

To the endpoint

```
[…path to the file…]:/copy
```

As follows

```
requests.post('[…path to the file…]BusinessDailyTemplate.xlsb:/copy',
              json={'parentReference': {'path': '/drive/root:/Main'}, 'name': 'BusinessDailyTemplate.xlsb'},
              headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer [...long authorisation token...]'})
```

As of this Saturday, all similar requests get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError",
        "message": "Unknown Error",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "b82e6e21-b75c-4e18-a6fe-5d6a8e4ec99e",
            "date": "2017-11-06T19:11:50"
        }
    }
}
```

There have been no code changes since Thursday, and the queries worked well on Thursday as well as Friday. They suddenly stopped working on Saturday. Therefore, we are pretty sure the problem isn’t with the code.

We are completely stuck after a few days of testing and brainstorming. Could you help us out?

Comment: We are having a similar issue using Microsoft Graph SDK since last monday, please someone help!!

Comment: I've reported this issue on the MSDN social site as well - if anyone cares to follow my communicatins with them: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/93ed704b-624c-4f05-b4ea-ae2a64743693/ms-graph-api-unknown-error-when-trying-to-get-folders-children-via-relative-pathing?forum=appsforsharepoint

Comment: This was [confirmed as an error on the MS side and has been resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47294110/100297).